# Ionic Controller 'ionNavBar', required by directive 'ionNavTitle', can't be found

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, navbar

I have quite a few templates defined the same way but on two particular templates, both using the same controller, I am getting the above error when the app renders those two pages.   It doesn't appear to be impacting my app but I don't like seeing it.

The two pages, from templates, start as:

```
<ion-view>
  <ion-nav-title>
    <div style="float:none;width:100%;text-align:center;" class="appTitle">APP REGISTRATION</div>
  </ion-nav-title> 
  <ion-content style="margin-top:0px;padding:10px;">
  ....
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

All my pages look essentially the same and are sub-components of the main index.html file:

```
  <body ng-app="starter">
    <!--
      The nav bar that will be updated as we navigate between views.
    -->
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
      <ion-nav-back-button>
      </ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <!--
      The views will be rendered in the <ion-nav-view> directive below
      Templates are in the /templates folder (but you could also
      have templates inline in this html file if you'd like).
    -->
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
  </body>
```

In the controller I am disabling backbuttons - allowing users to use them on the app registration pages causes the app to reload improperly causing errors but I don't think this should be impacting anything:

```
  var disableBack = $ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
  }, 100);

  $ionicNavBarDelegate.showBackButton(false);
```

What can I look at to get rid of these errors?

Answer (score 0):

The `ion-nav-bar` should be placed inside the `ion-nav-view`. Change the code like this in the index.html

```
<ion-nav-view>
   <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
      <ion-nav-back-button> </ion-nav-back-button>
   </ion-nav-bar>
</ion-nav-view>
```

Comment: I tried your approach thinking it wouldn't work and I was correct.  All my other pages work just fine the way the index.html file is set - and thats the default way IONIC releases their `tab-menu` template - changing it to your suggestion didn't work as I still get the same error.   Something else is going on and I can't figure out what.